# Can I install Ubuntu onto/replace a Windows mobile phone

Tags: windows-8

I have a Bush Windows 8.1 mobile, which has 8gb internal memory and supports upto 32gb micro card.
Can I install the Ubuntu mobile phone system and replace the Windows OS?
I am not technically minded, so installation needs to be as simple as installing on a desktop.

Comment: The Windows Phone's bootloader is locked. Well, [almost](http://www.windowscentral.com/windows-rt-lumia-520-hacked). There is currently [one way](http://www.wpinternals.net/) which may give you a chance but it is too difficult and has a lot of driver issues. Not to mention that you may essentially brick your device once and for all.

Comment: Hi Ashhar Hasan, thanks for replying and sending me the link. Not sure I understand the video at the moment, it will need time for me to work it out.